# Настройка почты laravel на OpenServer

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, как настроить почту, чтобы письма сохранялись локально в temp/email на OpenServer?
Если я использую код на отправку писем в чистом PHP без laravel, то почта сохраняется нормально, а вот в Laravel все идет через настройки в файле .env, а как их настроить, чтобы все сохранялось локально, потому что сейчас только через удаленный SMTP. (мне нужно это для теста, чтобы не использовать ящики).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для тестов вы можете воспользоваться логами самого Framework Laravel

```
MAIL_MAILER=LOG
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, использовать пакет [tkeer/mailbase](https://github.com/tkeer/mailbase).

Установка:

```
composer require tkeer/mailbase --dev
php artisan migrate
```

Затем прописать в конфиге `MAIL_MAILER=mailbase`.

Плюс этого способа - можно смотреть письма в веб-интерфейсе (`/mailbase`).

Также есть команда для очистки базы `php artisan mailbase:clear`